# Subjective usages of 'this' in C#

Tags: c#, documentation, this

I come from C++ and normally `this` is rarely used compared to C#. In my experience, the usage of `this` is strictly limited to scope and/or name resolution.

I have coworkers that insist that using `this` everywhere makes code "more clear". They essentially depend on it for documentation purposes. I disagree with this usage as it is very subjective, redundant, and practically useless as far as documentation is concerned.

There are cases where I see `this.myClassVariable = 100;`. In this case, `this` serves no real use other than (according to my coworkers) to make it very clear that `myClassVariable` is not a static. This is just one example.

Personally, where ever there are no ambiguities, I use `myClassVariable = 100;`. This is more clear and I feel honestly that if your variables are well named, code will be self documenting and 'this' is not needed.

What is the general rule of thumb on using 'this'? I'm asking for use cases that go beyond the obvious requirements (such as resolving ambiguities). There are cases where the usage of `this` is required for code to compile and I'm not necessarily interested in those cases. How do you guys feel about using `this` for documentation?

Comment: When your coworkers say it makes the code more clear and you say it makes it less clear, that right there tells you it's a subjective topic. Put 100 C# developers in a room and I imagine it'll be close to 50/50.

Comment: This should probably be moved to programmers.

Comment: There are two schools of thought:

  1. Those that say that fields shouldn't be prefixed with anything, i.e. `myClassVariable` is the correct name for a field. They need `this.` for exactly the reason they tell you: To know that they are accessing a member variable and not a local one.
  2. Those that say that fields should be prefixed with *something* - be it `m_` or `_`. They don't need `this` and don't use it.

Comment: I'm with you on this one, using this.myVariable everywhere just doesn't seem necessary and in my opinion, would actually make the code look more cluttered and therefore less readable.  My company isn't exactly big on documentation though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they want to distinguish static variables from private instance variables, why not use a naming convention to distinguish the two, instead of requiring `this`? For example, for private instance variables, prefix them with an underscore and name them using camel case (e.g. `_myVariable`). Then, for static variables, use Pascal case with no prefix (e.g. `MyStaticVariable`). It allows for simple disambiguation between static and instance variables, and doesn't require the extra key strokes and general "ugliness" required for `this`.

Answer (score 2):

I personally strongly object to this usage. Makes refactoring very hard - if you want to change a variable to a static or a local, you have to go through all usage points and get rid of `this.`.

This usage was possibly motivated by PHP or Python where it's a must.